# Strange problems when creating a float array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point

Code:

```
#define N 4
float unknowns[N] = {71/129, 539/1461, 1493/8507, 17/33};
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cout << unknowns[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl;
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0
```

For some reason the program is outputing the numbers in the array as integers and not as floats and I don't know why. How can I fix this?

This code for example works, and I tried casting them in the array itself but it still didn't work:

```
cout << (float)71/129 << " " << (float)539/1461 << " " << (float)1493/8507 << " " << (float)17/33 << endl;
```

Output:

```
0.550388 0.368925 0.175503 0.515152
```

Comment: Those are all integer division operations. Just because you're putting them into a `float` array doesn't mean the operations themselves are implicitly cast prior to the divisions. If you tried "casting them in the array itself" and it didn't work, that code should be included in your question.

Comment: Add a `.0` to the numbers.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well I also tried casting them in the array as follows: "float unknowns[N] = {(float)(71/129), (float)(539/1461), (float)(1493/8507), (float)(17/33)};" but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Déjàvu it worked, thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `(float)71/129` and `(float)(71/129)` are equivalent? The latter is no better than just leaving out the `float` in the first place, as the conversion post-division is implicit anyway whence stuffing into the array. Unrelated, you don't need  the zero in`.0`, you can just use `.`, as in `71./129` for example. It's a language thing (though this uses `double` values that are then trimmed to `float`; if you want `float` s from inception it would be proper to use `71.f/129`).

Comment: @User_Not_Found If you use cast like `float unknowns[N] = {float(71)/129, float(539)/1461, float(1493)/8507, float(17)/33};` it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are doing integer division (e.g., 71/129) and storing the value later in float. The result of integer is division of all your values is 0.

Use float division while constructing the array (use 71.0/129.0).

The code is:

```
define N 4
float unknowns[N] = {71.0/129.0, 539.0/1461.0, 1493.0/8507.0, 17.0/33.0};
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cout << unknowns[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl
```

Answer (score 4):

The numbers you shown are implicitely casted to integers, thus the result is always zeros, and thats what you get by the zero results. When you tell the compiler those are floats (e. g. by adding a zero) the result is also a float. Heres a working code example:

```
int main() {
    int N = 4;
    float unknowns[N] = {71.0/129.0, 539.0/1461.0, 1493.0/8507.0, 17.0/33.0};
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        std::cout << unknowns[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```